# Sort Sheets Alphabetically VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, sorting

I'm struggling on how will I sort the sheets after combining all workbooks into 1.

here's my code:

```
Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim mypath As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim saveFolder As String

Dim i%, j%

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

mypath = "C:\Acct. Docs" 'Change to suit
Set wbDst = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
strFilename = Dir(mypath & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)
Dim fname As String

saveFolder = "C:\FORMATTED"

If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

Do Until strFilename = ""
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=mypath & "\" & strFilename)
    Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)
    wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)
    wbSrc.Close False

    For i = 1 To wbDst.Worksheets.Count - 1
        For j = 1 To wbDst.Worksheets.Count
            If wbDst.Worksheets(j).Name < wbDst.Worksheets(i + 1).Name Then
                wbDst.Worksheets(j).Move Before:=Sheets(i + 1)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    strFilename = Dir()
Loop


wbDst.Worksheets(1).Delete
fname = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").Text
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs saveFolder & "\" & fname & " Account Documentation.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
wbDst.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

I want the sheets to be sorted alphabetically.
thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Ohh! I already figured it out!! :D
I just swap the conditions in Looping :D

```
 For i = 1 To wbDst.Worksheets.Count
        For j = 1 To wbDst.Worksheets.Count - 1
            If wbDst.Worksheets(i).Name < wbDst.Worksheets(j + 1).Name Then
                wbDst.Worksheets(i).Move Before:=Sheets(j + 1)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
```